# React is not displaying Rich-Text-Content from django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django as backend and react as frontend, I am using tinymce to create description in django-admin page , But react is displaying description content with html tags

Ouput:

```
<p>Best Cough Syrup</p>
```

I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML but page is not loading any content

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={product.description} />
```

Is there any way to solve this issue

Comment: And how do you pass the data from Django to react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
    <div 
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:product.description}}
    >
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,Its working